# Dúvida em filtrar uma Query no SQL

Tags: sql

Como que eu posso filtrar uma Query para que não apareça os "Clientes" com mais de um telefone, que no caso seria o Carlos como segue a imagem abaixo. Estou quebrando a cabeça e não acho em lugar nenhum na net este comando.

Desde-já agradeço!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Query* em causa:

```
SELECT      C.IDCLIENTE
        ,   C.NOME
        ,   C.SEXO
        ,   E.BAIRRO
        ,   T.TIPO
        ,   T.NUMERO
FROM        CLIENTE C
INNER JOIN  ENDERECO E ON C.IDCLIENTE = E.ID_CLIENTE
INNER JOIN  TELEFONE T ON C.IDCLIENTE = T.ID_CLIENTE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Penso que desta forma conseguirá chegar ao que pretende:

```
SELECT      C.IDCLIENTE
        ,   C.NOME
        ,   C.SEXO
        ,   E.BAIRRO
        ,   T.TIPO
        ,   T.NUMERO
FROM        CLIENTE C
INNER JOIN  ENDERECO E ON C.IDCLIENTE = E.ID_CLIENTE
INNER JOIN  TELEFONE T ON C.IDCLIENTE = T.ID_CLIENTE
INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT      C.IDCLIENTE
                        ,   COUNT(1)
                FROM        CLIENTE     C
                INNER JOIN  TELEFONE    T ON C.IDCLIENTE = T.ID_CLIENTE
                GROUP BY    C.IDCLIENTE
                HAVING      COUNT(1) <= 1
            ) C2 ON C2.IDCLIENTE = C.IDCLIENTE
```

Não testei no MySQL, mas penso que a sintaxe está correta.

Comment: Funcionou amigo, pô muito obrigado, tenho que estudar mais pois tem algumas coisas que você fez que eu não estudei ainda. Obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Ola Paulo, esse método do Joao, apesar de funcionar não tem uma boa performance, devido a quantidade de joins feitos que poderiam não existir.

Answer (score 3):

Acho que o metodo do Joao deve funcionar, mas nao vejo o porque de fazer um outro `inner join`, eu o faria assim:

```
SELECT      C.IDCLIENTE
        ,   C.NOME
        ,   C.SEXO
        ,   E.BAIRRO
        ,   T.TIPO
        ,   T.NUMERO
FROM        CLIENTE C
INNER JOIN  ENDERECO E ON C.IDCLIENTE = E.ID_CLIENTE
INNER JOIN  (   SELECT      T1.IDCLIENTE
                        ,   T1.TIPO
                        ,   T1.NUMERO
                FROM        TELEFONE T1
                GROUP BY    T1.IDCLIENTE
                HAVING      COUNT(1) <= 1
            ) T ON T.IDCLIENTE = C.IDCLIENTE
```

Estou fazendo um `inner join` com o que eu quero dos resultados da tabela Telefone, ou seja, me interessam somente os dados onde não exista mais de um `IDCLIENTE` igual na tabela `TELEFONE`.

Não testei o código, mas acho que esteja correto. Pelo menos a ideia do que se deve fazer você já tem

Comment: Ah sim, muito obrigado.